# Understanding the relationship between $F[\alpha]$ and $F(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm new to abstract algebra, however I don't have many resources, only my teachers' handout (I'm no longer their students). There's several place I don't know what is happening, and I have tried to figure it out by myself, but it's so hard. Thus I ask here. Let $E,~F$ are fields and $F\leq E$. Let $\alpha\in E$ and $\phi_{\alpha}$ be its evaluation homomorphism. Suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$. We know that $F[x]/\langle \textbf{irr}(\alpha,F)\rangle\cong \phi_{\alpha}(F[x])$ by the first isomorphism theorem. (Since $\langle \textbf{irr}(\alpha,F)\rangle$ is a maximal ideal, $\phi_{\alpha}(F[x])$ is a field.)

- Q1: Do we literally *define* $F[\alpha]$ (rather than finding it is equal to or isomorphic to) by $\phi_{\alpha}(F[x])$? Is $F[\alpha]$ a custom 
  symbol? Is there a name for such thing?
- Q2: Is the symbol $F(\alpha)$ again a custom one? Is there a name for such thing?
- Q3: I somehow feel that the definition of $F(\alpha)$ is exactly the quotient field of $F[\alpha]$. Is it?
- Q4: If what I guessed in Q3 is correct, then why do we need to put so many effort to prove that $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$ in this case (see my teacher's proof in the second picture)? I mean, since $F[\alpha]$ is a field, then its quotient field is equal to it by the trivial reason.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. $F[\alpha]$ is defined as the smallest subring of $E$ containing $F$ as subring and $\alpha$.
In other words, $F[\alpha]$ is the intersection of all subrings of $E$ containing $F$ as subring and $\alpha$.
Equivalently, $F[\alpha]$ is equal (not only isomorphic) to the image of your evaluation homomorphism $\phi_\alpha$.
Note that $F[\alpha]$ is not, in general, a field, but it's always a ring.

We concern with the ring $F[\alpha]$ because it's property of being image of $\phi_a$ permits us to define ring homomorphisms with domain $F[\alpha]$.
Indeed, recall the following universal property of polynomial rings:

> Let $\xi:F\to E$ be a field homomorphism, $X$ indeterminate
>   (transcendental) over $F$ and $\alpha\in E$. Then there exists a unique
>   ring homomorphism $\hat\xi:F[X]\to E$ extending $\xi$ and sending $X$
>   to $\alpha$.

This is the key property which is used to define the evaluation homomorphism $\phi_\alpha$.
Note that a similar property doesn't holds for $F(\alpha)$ and $F(X)$.

Q2. $F(\alpha)$ is defined as the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $F$ as subfield and $\alpha$.
Then $F(\alpha)$ is always a field which contains $F[\alpha]$ as subring.

Q3. Yes, $F(\alpha)$ is the field of fractions of $F[\alpha]$.

Q4. As you said, $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$ if and only if $F[\alpha]$ is a field and this happens if and only if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

On the other hand, when $\alpha$ is not algebraic (and it is said to be transcendent) over $F$, then $F[\alpha]$ is not a field and it's a proper subring of $F(\alpha)$.
In this case, $F[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to the ring of polynomial in one indeterminate while $F(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to the field of rational function in one indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks. For Q1, I wonder why we concern about the smallest subring that contains $F$ and $\alpha$? (Mainly due to I haven't studied the consequent materials in abstract algebra.) Is such need arise naturally? Would it be less natrual if I just defined it as the image of evaluation homomorphism? And how do we remember the $[]$ vs $()$, I don't know why the symbol is chosen as so weird, rather than something probably like $\langle F,\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: I added some details on this in the answer.

Comment: You can define $F[\alpha]$ also as the image $\phi_\alpha$: this is equivalent to my definition.

Comment: The symbols $[]$ and $()$ are frequently used in field theory. However, it's enough to remember $[]$:smallest subring and $()$:smallest subfield.

Comment: Are the $[]$ in guass integer domain $\Bbb Z[i]$ and in the general polynomial ring $\Bbb R[x]$ correspoding the similar "smallest ... " meaning? And by the way, I've seen some people using $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]:=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,~b\in\Bbb Q\}$, it may have some overlap.

Comment: Yes: $\Bbb Z[i]$ is the smallest subring of $\Bbb C$ containing $\Bbb Z$ as subring and $i$. Also for the polynomial ring the meaning holds. $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is the smallest subring of $\Bbb R$ containing $\Bbb Q$ as subring and $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I see. So I should always think of $X[\xi]$ as the smallest ring that contains $X$ as subring and $\xi$, and $Y(\eta)$ as the smallest field that contains $Y$ as subfield and $\eta$? So follow this rule, I'll never see something like $\Bbb Z(\xi)$, since $\Bbb Z$ is not a field.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Nobody has talked to me this important matter before.. Thanks for the help!